# Piwik tracking code inclusion

Tags: matomo

I am working on implementing Piwik on my website. I've included the tracking code just before the `</body>` on each page and have Piwk appropriately (I think) on my server. It doesn't work, and I'm starting the process of finding out why. I have two current questions:

First, the tracking code is:

```
<!-- Piwik --> <script type="text/javascript">
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://terryliittschwager.com/analytics/" : "http://terryliittschwager.com/analytics/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script><script type="text/javascript">
try {
var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 1);
piwikTracker.trackPageView();
piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
} catch( err ) {}
</script>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

I see that the code is split into two `<script></script>` sections. Why is that necessary? Would it not work as a single script?

Second, rather than placing the tracking code in each web page, would it also work if there was a `<script src='trackingcode.js'></script>` just before the `</body>`?

I've tried these alternate ways while attempting to get it to work, but as of yet no success.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

I would try moving to the ASYNC code which is the new code. It should also improve performance

```
<!-- Piwik --> <script type="text/javascript"> 
var _paq = _paq || []; 
(function(){ var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://{$PIWIK_URL}/" : "http://{$PIWIK_URL}/"); 
_paq.push(['setSiteId', {$IDSITE}]); 
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']); 
_paq.push(['trackPageView']); 
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']); 
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript'; g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); })();
 </script> 
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-where-can-i-find-the-piwik-tracking-code